# Minor solr schema changes without reindexing

Tags: indexing, solr, schema

I'm wondering whether or not it would be possible to change the type of 3 unused fields in my schema without reindexing everything. As mentioned, the fields are currently unused, and will only now, after my change, be used.

After a cursory check in a sample server, it seems this is possible, and I won't suffer any scoring loss - am I right about this?

Thanks,
Rasmus Edvardsen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fields that haven't been used can be changed as you see fit, yes. They're not defined inside the Lucene index before actually being used (the "schema" is what Solr uses to force a specific type from the input).